# Zend Framework Soap WSDL

Tags: zend-framework, soap

I have a working SOAP service that uses PHP/Zend Framework SOAP.  The problem I am having is the WSDL needs to implement "xsd:decimal" instead of "xsd:int".

Using the AutoDiscovery method on the following snippet:

```
/* @var decimal */
public $prize;
```

returns the following error:

> Cannot add a complex type decimal that is not an object or where class could not be found in 'DefaultComplexType' strategy.

Using a class map doesn't seem to fix the issue.  Is there any way to use "xsd:decimal" with the AutoDiscovery method?

The following snippet works fine, but shows "xsd:int" in the WSDL:

```
/* @var int */
public $prize
```

Answer (score 1):

use float

PHP floats and doubles <-> xsd:float.

Comment: I can't use float.  I need the auto-generated WSDL to show "decimal" (don't ask why, it's not my choice).

Comment: It seems the SOAP client for this service "requires xsd:decimal".  No, I don't know why either...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use decimal.

But have you tried using a complex type named decimal, that maps to a float?

```
class decimal
{
/** @var float */
public $prize;
}
```

You need also to define the correct autodiscover strategy:

```
$autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeComplex');
```